# jQuery scroll to highlighted element on really messy content, help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay, quite time ago, I have made a jquery script with help of highlight plugin which enables you to enter a term in input, which gets highlighted in the text and then you can scroll, with click on next or previous button, from one highlighted span element, to another.

it is really cool, you can try to play around with clicking on button on this link: http://jsfiddle.net/m6ZMp/

Now I have a need to use this `highlight/scroll` script on some messy html code, which I located in same demo container as the text in previous example. Highlight of searched terms works without the problems but I'm getting error on click to my `prev` and `next` buttons. It is because I'm using them to scroll from one highlighted word to another like that:

```
count = 0;
$('#next1').click(function (e) {
    var max_length = $('.highlight1').length;
        if (count < max_length) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count = 1;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        scrollToElement('.highlight1:nth-child(' + count + ')', 400, -150);
    });

    $('#prev1').click(function (e) {
    var max_length = $('.highlight1').length;
        if (count > 1) {
            count--;
        } else {
            count = max_length;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        scrollToElement('.highlight1:nth-child(' + count + ')', 400, -150);
    })
```

I have that count which I'm using for getting the number of found elements and then at the end of each click function I'm passing int to `scrollToElement` function as part of selector `'.highlight1:nth-child(' + count + ')'`. Now I assume that I have problems because in that messy documents, higlighted terms are no more on same level, they are not sibling or children of same element, and because of that my function does not work well.

it gives me error on `scrollToElement` function:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null

you can see, test out and edit situation in here: http://jsfiddle.net/9EDSp/

the whole script looks like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#field1').bind('keyup change', function (ev) {
        // pull in the new value
        var searchTerm = $(this).val();

        // remove any old highlighted terms
        $('#demo-container').removeHighlight('span.highlight1');

        // disable highlighting if empty
        if (searchTerm) {
            var terms = searchTerm.split(/\s+/);
            $.each(terms, function (_, term) {
                // highlight the new term
                term = term.trim();
                if (term != "") $('#demo-container').highlight(term, 'highlight1');
            });

        }
    }).triggerHandler('change');

});

    /**  scroll to element function **/

    function scrollToElement(selector, time, verticalOffset) {
        time = typeof (time) != 'undefined' ? time : 500;
        verticalOffset = typeof (verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;
        element = $(selector);
        offset = element.offset();
        offsetTop = offset.top + verticalOffset + $('#demo-container').scrollTop();
        $('#demo-container').animate({
            scrollTop: offsetTop
        }, time);
    }

    /**document ready**/
    $(document).ready(function () {
        count = 0;
        /* scroll to 150px before .highlight with animation time of 400ms */
        $('#next1').click(function (e) {
        var max_length = $('.highlight1').length;
            if (count < max_length) {
                count++;
            } else {
                count = 1;
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            scrollToElement('.highlight1:nth-child(' + count + ')', 400, -150);
        });

        $('#prev1').click(function (e) {
        var max_length = $('.highlight1').length;
            if (count > 1) {
                count--;
            } else {
                count = max_length;
            }
            e.preventDefault();
            scrollToElement('.highlight1:nth-child(' + count + ')', 400, -150);
        })
    });
```

Do I just need to use different selectors to scroll from one term to another or simply I need something more than this current code?

Any advice, suggestion or help is welcome....

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting all of the element highlight1 using a $.each() loop, and add each one to an array. Use the current count as the index, and select the correct index for the element you need to move to. Then scroll to that element. So pass an jQuery object / element instead of the selector, and map the element in ScrollToElement function to the object you passed, instead of the selector you passed. Using nth-child selects the (n) CHILD element to that parent, not the (N) item in the list returned by $('.highlight1').

Or, you could use .index() to select the highlight1 item at that index/count you are at. Remeber though, index will fall one short of your count. Array based!

Hopefully that makes sense on how I explained it.

Comment: sounds like it should work... I will try to solve something according to my jsfiddle, if I'm stuck, I'll link back where I stopped and hope I'll get some help from you? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    I have modified the above code to work similar to page search in chrome . 
    Also added  below features
    1)added a stop word filter to remove unwanted terms being highlighted (eg a-z , an ,at etc)
    2)Change in highlight color between term navigation.




    jsp file:
 -----------------------------
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"><%@page
    language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>highlight</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="GENERATOR"
    content="Rational® Application Developer for WebSphere® Software">


<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jquery.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/highlight2.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>    

<style type="text/css">
    @import url('http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/assets/css/bootstrap.css');

#outer{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    padding-top:50px;
}
#demo-container{
   width:200%;
   height:150%;
    overflow:auto;
}

.dock{
    position:fixed;
    background:#FFFFFF;
}

.prev-highlight {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    /* FF1+ */
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    /* Saf3-4 */
    border-radius: 5px;
    /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Saf5, Chrome */
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    /* FF3.5+ */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    /* Saf3.0+, Chrome */
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    /* Opera 10.5+, IE 9.0 */
}

.prev-highlight{
    background-color: #fff34d;
     padding:1px 4px;
      margin:0 -4px;
}



 .prev-highlight-selected {
background-color: #FF8000;
}
  </style>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$(function () {
    $('#field1').bind('keyup change', function (ev) {
        // pull in the new value
        var searchTerm = $(this).val();
        searchTerm=searchTerm.removeStopWords();

        // remove any old highlighted terms
        $('#demo-container').removeHighlight('span.prev-highlight');

        // disable highlighting if empty
        if (searchTerm) {
            var terms = searchTerm.split(/\s+/);
            $.each(terms, function (_, term) {
                // highlight the new term
               // term = term.trim();
                if (term != "") $('#demo-container').highlight(term, 'prev-highlight');
            });

        }
    }).triggerHandler('change');

});

    /**  scroll to element function **/

    function scrollToElement(selector, time, verticalOffset) {

         selectedKeyword = $('.prev-highlight-selected');
     if (selectedKeyword) selectedKeyword.removeClass('prev-highlight-selected');
      $(selector).addClass('prev-highlight-selected');


        time = typeof (time) != 'undefined' ? time : 500;
        verticalOffset = typeof (verticalOffset) != 'undefined' ? verticalOffset : 0;

        element = $(selector);
        offset = element.offset();
      //  alert(offset.top);
        offsetTop = offset.top + verticalOffset + $('#demo-container').scrollTop();
        $('#demo-container').animate({
            scrollTop: offsetTop
        }, time);

    }

    /**document ready**/
    $(document).ready(function () {

        count = 0;


        /* scroll to 150px before .highlight with animation time of 400ms */
        $('#next1').click(function (e) {        
        count++;
        var max_length = $('.prev-highlight').length;
        var child =  (count-1)% max_length ;

            if (count == max_length) {
                count=0;
            } 
                        e.preventDefault();
            scrollToElement('.prev-highlight:eq(' + child + ')', 400, -150);
        });

        $('#prev1').click(function (e) {    
        var max_length = $('.prev-highlight').length;       
        count--;
        if (count <=0)
        {                
        count=max_length;                        
        }

   var  child =  (count-1)% max_length ;

            e.preventDefault();
            scrollToElement('.prev-highlight:eq(' + child + ')', 400, -150);
        });
    });
});

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="dock">
<input class="span3" id="field1" name="field1" value="external and a internal you z" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="Search">
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" id="prev1" href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-up icon-white"></i></a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" id="next1" href="#"><i class="icon-arrow-down icon-white"></i></a>
    </div>






  <div id="outer">
<div id="demo-container">
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #ffc000; font-size: 18pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <i><b>Vanity URL creation</b></i>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <i><b>Step 1: </b></i>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        We have to receive the domain name.
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=ListaParagraph>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=ListaParagraph>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        For example,
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=ListaParagraph>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 16pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <b></b>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=ListaParagraph>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 16pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <b>www. training.com or ideas. .com. </b>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=ListaParagraph>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 16pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <b>It could be an individual domain name or it could be sub domain of  .com.</b>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 16pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <b></b>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <i><b>Step 2:</b></i>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        We need to check with business whether this should be only  Honeywell use or this
        is for both  external.
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <i><b>Step 3:</b></i>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=ListaParagraph>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        We need to check with the customer if https should work for this vanity domain or not. If
        https is expected to work, we have to convey them that this involves additional
      </span>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <b>SSL certificate cost.</b>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <i><b>Step 4:</b></i>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>

    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        For example, when user access ideas. .com, they should be redirected to .
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        Here is the sample,
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        Please note that the IP address, Port number and the log file pathfile name will change
        for each of the web server.
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <i><b>Step 6:</b></i>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        If the application is expected to work in https, then we have to put two entries. One with
        http port and other with https port.
      </span>
    </p>

      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <b></b>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <b></b>
      </span>
    </p>


     <p class=default>

    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        We need to check with business whether this should be only  Honeywell use or this
        is for both  external.
      </span>
    </p>

    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <i><b>Step 3:</b></i>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>

    </p>
    <p class=ListaParagraph>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>

      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        If the application to which this vanity domain is pointing to is deployed in BK, then we
        will define the vhost in Bendix/King apache.
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=ListaParagraph>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>


    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <i><b>Step 7:</b></i>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        Once the above step is done, we can validate the vhost entry using local host file. We
        have to validate before we make DNS entry. To test with local host file, you have to find
        the internal facing IP of apache (internal CSS IP) and external facing IP. This is usually
        documented at the top of the apache include file. Refer the snapshot below.
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        Find below the sample local host file entry. The local host file is usually found in Win
        XP under the path
      </span>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <b>C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\.</b>
      </span>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
         The name of the file is "
      </span>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <b>hosts</b>
      </span>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        ". If the domain is suppose to work from both internal and external network, then we have
        to validate with both the IPs
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <b>  qideas. .com</b>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <i><b>Step 8:</b></i>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        Once validated, we have to raise DNS ticket. If the URL is meant to be for internal, then
        we just need to raise a ticket with  DNS group. If it is for both, please create
        tickets for both the group.
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <i>Example CRQ Number is</i>
      </span>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <b> </b>
      </span>
      <span style="color: #548dd4; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <b></b>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #ff0000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <i><b>Step 9:</b></i>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        Once the DNS ticket is executed, validate with browser and then also with
      </span>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">

      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <b></b>
      </span>
    </p>
    <p class=default>
      <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 12pt; font-family: Times New Roman">
        <b></b>
      </span>
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>








-----------------
highlight2 javascript file:


jQuery.fn.highlight = function (pat, className) {

    function innerHighlight(node, pat) {
        var skip = 0;
        if (node.nodeType == 3) {
            var pos = node.data.toUpperCase().indexOf(pat);
            if (pos >= 0) {
                var spannode = document.createElement('span');
                spannode.className = className || 'prev-highlight';
                var middlebit = node.splitText(pos);
                var endbit = middlebit.splitText(pat.length);
                var middleclone = middlebit.cloneNode(true);
                spannode.appendChild(middleclone);
                middlebit.parentNode.replaceChild(spannode, middlebit);
                skip = 1;
            }
        } else if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.childNodes && !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName)) {
            for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; ++i) {
                i += innerHighlight(node.childNodes[i], pat);
            }
        }
        return skip;
    }
    return this.each(function () {
        innerHighlight(this, pat.toUpperCase());
    });
};

jQuery.fn.removeHighlight = function (classNames) {
    function newNormalize(node) {
        for (var i = 0, children = node.childNodes, nodeCount = children.length; i < nodeCount; i++) {
            var child = children[i];
            if (child.nodeType == 1) {
                newNormalize(child);
                continue;
            }
            if (child.nodeType != 3) {
                continue;
            }
            var next = child.nextSibling;
            if (next == null || next.nodeType != 3) {
                continue;
            }
            var combined_text = child.nodeValue + next.nodeValue;
            new_node = node.ownerDocument.createTextNode(combined_text);
            node.insertBefore(new_node, child);
            node.removeChild(child);
            node.removeChild(next);
            i--;
            nodeCount--;
        }
    }
    var selectors = classNames;
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(classNames) === '[object Array]')
      selectors = classNames.join(',');

    return this.find(selectors).each(function () {
        var thisParent = this.parentNode;
        thisParent.replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
        newNormalize(thisParent);
    }).end();
};



String.prototype.removeStopWords = function() {
    var x;
    var y;
    var word;
    var stop_word;
    var regex_str;
    var regex;
    var cleansed_string = this.valueOf();
    var stop_words = new Array(
        'a',
        'about',
        'above',
        'across',
        'after',
        'again',
        'against',
        'all',
        'almost',
        'alone',
        'along',
        'already',
        'also',
        'although',
        'always',
        'among',
        'an',
        'and',
        'another',
        'any',
        'anybody',
        'anyone',
        'anything',
        'anywhere',
        'are',
        'area',
        'areas',
        'around',
        'as',
        'ask',
        'asked',
        'asking',
        'asks',
        'at',
        'away',
        'b',
        'back',
        'backed',
        'backing',
        'backs',
        'be',
        'became',
        'because',
        'become',
        'becomes',
        'been',
        'before',
        'began',
        'behind',
        'being',
        'beings',
        'best',
        'better',
        'between',
        'big',
        'both',
        'but',
        'by',
        'c',
        'came',
        'can',
        'cannot',
        'case',
        'cases',
        'certain',
        'certainly',
        'clear',
        'clearly',
        'come',
        'could',
        'd',
        'did',
        'differ',
        'different',
        'differently',
        'do',
        'does',
        'done',
        'down',
        'down',
        'downed',
        'downing',
        'downs',
        'during',
        'e',
        'each',
        'early',
        'either',
        'end',
        'ended',
        'ending',
        'ends',
        'enough',
        'even',
        'evenly',
        'ever',
        'every',
        'everybody',
        'everyone',
        'everything',
        'everywhere',
        'f',
        'face',
        'faces',
        'fact',
        'facts',
        'far',
        'felt',
        'few',
        'find',
        'finds',
        'first',
        'for',
        'four',
        'from',
        'full',
        'fully',
        'further',
        'furthered',
        'furthering',
        'furthers',
        'g',
        'gave',
        'general',
        'generally',
        'get',
        'gets',
        'give',
        'given',
        'gives',
        'go',
        'going',
        'good',
        'goods',
        'got',
        'great',
        'greater',
        'greatest',
        'group',
        'grouped',
        'grouping',
        'groups',
        'h',
        'had',
        'has',
        'have',
        'having',
        'he',
        'her',
        'here',
        'herself',
        'high',
        'high',
        'high',
        'higher',
        'highest',
        'him',
        'himself',
        'his',
        'how',
        'however',
        'i',
        'if',
        'important',
        'in',
        'interest',
        'interested',
        'interesting',
        'interests',
        'into',
        'is',
        'it',
        'its',
        'itself',
        'j',
        'just',
        'k',
        'keep',
        'keeps',
        'kind',
        'knew',
        'know',
        'known',
        'knows',
        'l',
        'large',
        'largely',
        'last',
        'later',
        'latest',
        'least',
        'less',
        'let',
        'lets',
        'like',
        'likely',
        'long',
        'longer',
        'longest',
        'm',
        'made',
        'make',
        'making',
        'man',
        'many',
        'may',
        'me',
        'member',
        'members',
        'men',
        'might',
        'more',
        'most',
        'mostly',
        'mr',
        'mrs',
        'much',
        'must',
        'my',
        'myself',
        'n',
        'necessary',
        'need',
        'needed',
        'needing',
        'needs',
        'never',
        'new',
        'new',
        'newer',
        'newest',
        'next',
        'no',
        'nobody',
        'non',
        'noone',
        'not',
        'nothing',
        'now',
        'nowhere',
        'number',
        'numbers',
        'o',
        'of',
        'off',
        'often',
        'old',
        'older',
        'oldest',
        'on',
        'once',
        'one',
        'only',
        'open',
        'opened',
        'opening',
        'opens',
        'or',
        'order',
        'ordered',
        'ordering',
        'orders',
        'other',
        'others',
        'our',
        'out',
        'over',
        'p',
        'part',
        'parted',
        'parting',
        'parts',
        'per',
        'perhaps',
        'place',
        'places',
        'point',
        'pointed',
        'pointing',
        'points',
        'possible',
        'present',
        'presented',
        'presenting',
        'presents',
        'problem',
        'problems',
        'put',
        'puts',
        'q',
        'quite',
        'r',
        'rather',
        'really',
        'right',
        'right',
        'room',
        'rooms',
        's',
        'said',
        'same',
        'saw',
        'say',
        'says',
        'second',
        'seconds',
        'see',
        'seem',
        'seemed',
        'seeming',
        'seems',
        'sees',
        'several',
        'shall',
        'she',
        'should',
        'show',
        'showed',
        'showing',
        'shows',
        'side',
        'sides',
        'since',
        'small',
        'smaller',
        'smallest',
        'so',
        'some',
        'somebody',
        'someone',
        'something',
        'somewhere',
        'state',
        'states',
        'still',
        'still',
        'such',
        'sure',
        't',
        'take',
        'taken',
        'than',
        'that',
        'the',
        'their',
        'them',
        'then',
        'there',
        'therefore',
        'these',
        'they',
        'thing',
        'things',
        'think',
        'thinks',
        'this',
        'those',
        'though',
        'thought',
        'thoughts',
        'three',
        'through',
        'thus',
        'to',
        'today',
        'together',
        'too',
        'took',
        'toward',
        'turn',
        'turned',
        'turning',
        'turns',
        'two',
        'u',
        'under',
        'until',
        'up',
        'upon',
        'us',
        'use',
        'used',
        'uses',
        'v',
        'very',
        'w',
        'want',
        'wanted',
        'wanting',
        'wants',
        'was',
        'way',
        'ways',
        'we',
        'well',
        'wells',
        'went',
        'were',
        'what',
        'when',
        'where',
        'whether',
        'which',
        'while',
        'who',
        'whole',
        'whose',
        'why',
        'will',
        'with',
        'within',
        'without',
        'work',
        'worked',
        'working',
        'works',
        'would',
        'x',
        'y',
        'year',
        'years',
        'yet',
        'you',
        'young',
        'younger',
        'youngest',
        'your',
        'yours',
        'z'
    );


    words = cleansed_string.match(/[^\s]+|\s+[^\s+]$/g);

    // Review all the words
    for(x=0; x < words.length; x++) {
        // For each word, check all the stop words
        for(y=0; y < stop_words.length; y++) {
            // Get the current word
            word = words[x].replace(/\s+|[^a-z]+/ig, "");   // Trim the word and remove non-alpha

            // Get the stop word
            stop_word = stop_words[y];

            // If the word matches the stop word, remove it from the keywords
            if(word.toLowerCase() == stop_word) {
                // Build the regex
                regex_str = "^\\s*"+stop_word+"\\s*$";      // Only word
                regex_str += "|^\\s*"+stop_word+"\\s+";     // First word
                regex_str += "|\\s+"+stop_word+"\\s*$";     // Last word
                regex_str += "|\\s+"+stop_word+"\\s+";      // Word somewhere in the middle
                regex = new RegExp(regex_str, "ig");

                // Remove the word from the keywords
                cleansed_string = cleansed_string.replace(regex, " ");
            }
        }
    }
    return cleansed_string.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
}
```